# Is it possible in CSS use math like this?

Tags: css

I have elements with classes like

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
<div class="class5"></div>
...etc...
```

Somehow it possible to use 1 rule in css for all this classes?

 
Like

```
.class[1-5]{
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

this?

Or it possible only with JS?

Comment: A class can be applied to multiple objects so you only have to write one rule. So just give the same class to all the elements you want to target. Else you can do: .class-1, .class-2, etc.

Comment: in pure CSS you could only target all elements starting with `class`, e.g. `[class^="class"] { margin-top: 5px; }`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can just make all the elements the same class. so:

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

and just use the css:

```
.example    {
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

You are able to do this because class's can be applied to multiple elements (unlike id's) even if they are different types of element.

Answer (score 3):

Use [attribute-selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css3-attribute-selectors/) in css

```
[class ^= "class"] {

  margin-top:5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WBAz3/)

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: This looks like a useful answer, however, I really don't understand how the operator works in a more general case. Care to add an explanation or a link to one?

Comment: @vlrprbttst see the  link it is useful for you

Comment: `^=` means begins with. So select elements that begin with the `class` as part of their class.

Comment: At least qualify that thing with a div. Doing this is not recommended in general because it is very slow. It's only for use if you can qualify it to a small part of the page, not a global one like in the answer.

Comment: this just works in some limited condition, such as if there is some element having class `classfksdjfkdsjf4324`, it will also be targeted and styled.

Comment: You want to be careful with the begins with as it won't work if `class1` was the second class eg `<div class="example class1"></div>` wouldn't be styled

Comment: @KingKing , i didn't tell this answer satisfy with all your own condition. but it is satisfy OP question

Comment: @Ariel suppose i have more than 50 classes like above question you write .class1, .class2 it is a low quality code

Comment: @Sudharsan Have you asked OP that..? what's the point in having different classes to each and every elements..?

Comment: @Sudharsan If you had that, then put two classes on each div, one for the specific div, and one to use for the `margin` style.

Comment: @Ariel - It's a old way. that way css3 introduced attribute selector go and read

Comment: @Sudharsan I know that. But this is not a good place to use it. Yes, you answered the question - which is good. But he should know to A) not to actually use this without qualifying the selector, and B) that a second class is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Or even better, put two classes on your divs:

```
<div class="class1 marginClass"></div>

.marginClass {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```